# Разделение WiFi и Lan vlan'om

Tags: lan, vlan, сеть, wifi

Всем добрый день!

Задача стоит такая: раздать Инет платный по wifi с авторизацией пользователей и учетом трафика. (В сети 5 точек доступа(AP), которые подключены через разные неуправляемые свичи.) Для реализации этого выбор пал на EasyHotspot. Но в здании есть и Lan клиенты. Хотелось бы как-то разделить клиентов wi-fi от Lan. Чтоб у Lan машин не выскакивала страничка с авторизацией.

1. Можно ли это сделать при помощи vlan?
2. Или подскажите, как это сделать другим способом!

Comment: А Lan-клиенты тоже работают через те же точки доступа?

Answer (score 1):

можно lan клиентов настройить на автоматическую авторизацию по маку

http://dmitrykhn.homedns.org/wp/2010/07/static-ip-in-chillispot/

Answer (score 0):

Wifi точки подключаете к упр. коммутаторам, те порты которые в которые воткнули wifi точки, назначаете необходимой меткой 802.1Q, а те порты в которые подключены lan, другие идентификаторы 802.1Q. Тем самым получите wifi это vlan номер раз, lan это vlan номер два.

Comment: Только зачем?